# Batch files: Is there a command line in batch file to include input to stored procedure

Tags: mysql, batch-file

I have a stored procedure that is scheduled to run for 'X' days.Here X can be 1, 2,3 or 4.

In order to execute this stored proc, I run 'exec  NoOfDays=3'
Here NoOfDAys is the input parameter.

I have a batch file that is used to deploy this stored procedure.

My question is:

Is it possible to add a command line in my batch file to input the NoOfDays instead of executing in the stored procedure??
So the user need not go through the stored proc, instead open the batch file just input the integer and run the file.

Help me with this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer for this.

> SET Parameter=3 sqlcmd  -S %Server% -d
>   %DB%  -Q "EXEC
>   uspScheduleMonthlySubscription
>   %Parameter%"

initially I created a parameter and assigned value to it(this is where the user can input the value). Then the sqlcmd containing the stored procedure is executed with reference to the parameter.When this file is deployed,the stored procedure gets executed.

It worked.!:)
Thanks for ur help Dave..:)

Answer (score 1):

Say your batch file is called `batchForDays.bat` if you call `batchForDays 3` then you can use `%1` inside the batch file to pickup the first variable.

So if you have `exec NoOfDays=%1` inside `batchForDays.bat` then call `batchForDays 3` so it processes `exec NoOfDays=3`.

Comment: My batch file name is Deploy_CVBSQL.bat                         @echo off

cls

set Server=%ComputerName%
set UserId=-E
set DB=ReportServer ---database name where the sql is deployed
set fn=Deploy_CVB_SQL_Log.txt

if exist %fn% del %fn%
@echo on

sqlcmd -S %Server% %UserId% -d %DB% -I -i "%cd%"\SQL\spScheduleMonthlySubscription.sql >>  %fn% 2>&1 --this is the stored proc taht executes for 'x' days


NOw, where should I include this execute function?

Comment: @Iswarya Not sure how to pass the day into that line for \spScheduleMonthlySubscription.sql which is output to the %fn% file. If you have the correct syntax for that then use the %1 so you can call Deploy_CVBSQL 3 to pass in 3 days.